# joomla google translate based on user ip

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I have a joomla website.

I have integrated gtranslate, so that the user can select and translate the content to selected language.

*Header*

```
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="e6d65bc1aa004329-813ae7b5623659e0-g8b1cf8bac64e7822-16"></meta>
```

*Content*

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Is there anyway, i can do this automated, like automatically based on the user ip address, the language should be selected and site content should be translated.

Comment: I don't think it's a reliable way to determine the langauge. The country I live in has 2 native languages , English not being one of them. Because of a VPN to abroad your script would set it to English though.

Comment: You had a much better chance to get better answers if you formatted/cleared your question.

Comment: @geekynotsilly : so the two native languages should be from different places with different range of ips right ?

Comment: @PeterHorvath : can you please format the question on behalf of me.

Comment: @sparkz , no there is no way to accurately determine that at all. IP based language settings are not the way to go.

Comment: @geekynotsilly : can i able to achieve this with geoip ?